# CDI Extension - How to handle nonbinding values on qualifier

Tags: java, cdi

I am currently working on an CDI extension. I have to register some special custom beans, thats why a producer is not sufficient.

This is currently done inside the `AfterBeanDiscovery`-Phase by registering a custom implementation of `Bean<>` using the `abd.addBean()` method.

The drawback is that inside the `create()`-method of the bean I can't access the `InjectionPoint`, that may contain additional configuration inside an annotation.

As a possibility I could collect all beans I need in the `ProcessInjectionTarget` phase (as there I have access to the annotations) and register each of them inside the `AfterBeanDiscovery` phase. 
Then I would have to make the configuration annotation a qualifier and the attributes of the qualifier binding (not using `@Nonbinding`) to prevent ambigous dependencies.

But then I will register a huge amount of beans that just are different in their configuration.

Is there an alternate solution? Is it possible to access the `InjectionPoint` inside the beans `create()` method?

Thank you!

Comment: You state a producer is not sufficient, yet you don't back that up.  Why do you feel that a producer method is not sufficient here, it seems like it would do exactly what you want.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007892/cdi-producers-and-qualifiers-not-on-the-produced-object/31011324#31011324

Comment: Ok, so your use case is a bit confusing.  Yes, if someone wants to use a custom qualifier its going outside your framework.  Typically frameworks will create producers with parameters, typically strings.  DeltaSpike has a good example of such an implementation, using JPA mind you but the same idea is used here http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html#ObtainingEntityManagersfromJPA

Comment: So to be a little bit more concrete maybe (didn't want to bother with details): I am currently working on a CDI extension that allows you to inject Jenkins stuff by using e.g. `@JenkinsJob("JobName")`. For that purpose a producer is implemented by the developer that will produce an according JenkinsServer (e.g. ServerDev). Now the developer should be able to annotate the `@JenkinsJob` annotated member with a second annotation (Qualifier) that is used to determine which server to use (as his JenkinsServer-Producer will have the same qualifier). Does this help?

Comment: Just use @Nonbinding for JenkinsJob.value and provide a CDI-Producer with InjectionPoint as parameter. See e.g. https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/impl/config/DefaultConfigPropertyProducer.java#L41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

Basically I somehow needed to access the current `InjectionPoint` inside the beans `create()` method, that way one can also access the annotations of the injection point.

To get the injection point the following code snipped works (inspired by [OmniFaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces.github.io), using [Apache Deltaspike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/)):

```
public class InjectionPointGenerator {

  @Inject
  private InjectionPoint injectionPoint;

  public InjectionPoint getInjectionPoint() {
    return injectionPoint;
  }
}


public class BeanUtils {

  protected BeanUtils() {
    // Prevent instantiation
  }

  public static InjectionPoint getInjectionPoint(@Nonnull CreationalContext context) {
    Bean<InjectionPointGenerator> bean = getBean(InjectionPointGenerator.class);
    BeanManager beanManager = BeanManagerProvider.getInstance().getBeanManager();
    InjectionPoint injectionPoint = bean.getInjectionPoints().iterator().next();
    return (InjectionPoint) beanManager.getInjectableReference(injectionPoint, context);
  }

  private static <T> Bean<T> getBean(@Nonnull Class<T> type) {
    return BeanProvider.getBeanDefinitions(type, false, true).iterator().next();
  }
}
```